# Error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, static

I have a following piece of C++ code:

```
template <typename WorkType, int Degree = 2> class PolynomialFunction {
 public:
  static constexpr int kNumberCoefficients[] = { 0, 3, 6, 10, 15 };
  static const int kPolyDimension = kNumberCoefficients[Degree];
  ...
 private:
  WorkType polynom_[kPolyDimension];
  ...
```

which compiled fine before but suddenly (maybe new compiler) it fails with following errors:

> ./polynomial_function.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr const int
>   PolynomialFunction::kNumberCoefficients []':  
>   ./polynomial_function.h:84:56:   required from 'const int
>   PolynomialFunction::kPolyDimension'  
>   ./polynomial_function.h:309:35:   required from 'class
>   PolynomialFunction'    
>  ./segment.h:321:17:   required
>   from here  
>  ./polynomial_function.h:83:24: error: initializer
>   fails to determine size of 'PolynomialFunction::kNumberCoefficients'  
>  ./polynomial_function.h:83:24: error:
>   array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer   
>   ./polynomial_function.h: In instantiation of 'class
>   PolynomialFunction':   
>  ./segment.h:321:17: required
>   from here

Btw. line 83 is the declaration of 'kNumberCoefficients' and line 309 is the declaration of 'polynom_'. Any ideas why it is failing? Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the `=`.